# How to add multiple netty decoders and conditionally skip other if the first decoder/encoder pair serves the purpose

Tags: netty

I want to handle message of type "xx bytecount sid newline payload" and "xx 000 sid newline". I was using string encoder and decoder. Unfortunately that will not match the first one. I know that I can write a custom decoder and create a dynamic buffer and keep on injecting data until I meet the byte count for the payload. But how do I skip the string encoder and decoder if my custom encoder is hit successfully.

One more question . How do I read the rest of the count number of bytes in custom decoder . Suppose I am able to read the count how do I set it as a state variable to read further data

Comment: Sorry can you give more details..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I would just write a single decoder that decodes both message types.  If you insist to keep multiple decoders in the pipeline, you can also do that.

First, insert the decoder that decodes the first message type (xxx bytecount ...) into the pipeline.

Second, program the decoder does not bomb out when the second message type is encountered.  For the message type it does not understand, make it just forward the message to the next handler. Then the second decoder that decodes the second message type will decode it.

Third, program the second decoder that decodes the second message type (xxx 000 ...) checks if the received message is the message decoded by the first decoder.  If so, the second decoder should forward the message in verbatim to the next handler.